# C# How to sort int when value is too large

Tags: c#, sorting

```
8
723
77715926535897932384626433832795
```

Usually I will place them into Array and using `Sort` method to sort them numerically.

However, the above value is too huge to be place into `Int64` and if using `string` array, its gonna give unexpected outcome which 8 comes after `77715926535897932384626433832795`. How to sort such large value?

Comment: Use BigInteger https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And without BigInteger (slow): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612086/compare-very-large-numbers-stored-in-string/16612711#16612711

Answer (score 4):

You can always sort by length and then by value:

```
var numbers = new []
{
    "8",
    "77715926535897932384626433832795",
    "723",
};

var sorted =
    numbers
        .OrderBy(n => n.Length)
        .ThenBy(n => n)
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

```
8 
723 
77715926535897932384626433832795
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `int64` to store your value you can use `BigInteger` class from `System.Numerics` namespace.
If you want to use primitive types, then **float, double, long** are options for you.

[Primitive data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx) with approximate length

1. [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float) : -3.4 × 10^38 to +3.4 × 10^38
2. [double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double): ±5.0 × 10^−324 to ±1.7 × 10^308
3. [long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long): -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

For more information about: [System.Numerics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Sorting of BigInteger: [Look at this example](https://github.com/prasadtelkikar/HackerRank/blob/master/Algorithms/Arrays/Big%20Sorting.cs)

Now choice is yours. Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a requirement that the values need to be an integer, you can use a `double` instead of `Int64` for all of the values. The max value for a `double` is  1.7976931348623157E+308, so it's much bigger than the example one you showed. That will probably be an easy code change too. `BigInteger` will require some other code changes as people have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use a numeric datatype with greater capacity. The largest numeric datatype is the [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) which has 96 bits of precision (about 28 digits). There are also some other data types that are in between. In general it is best to use the datatype that is just large enough. With floating point data types, beware of loss of precision when there are too many significant digits.

If you are working with numbers so huge they won't fit into any of the numeric data types, you can sort an arbitrarily long integer by padding it with zeroes so they are all the same length.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputs = new string[] 
        {
            "77715926535897932384626433832795",
            "8",
            "2398798734",
            "0092",
            "12987981239871928379817231",
            "98279384792873498274908123946109478276492874927864928734872983476928739487298374"
        };

        //Determine the length of the longest number when expressed as a string
        var maxLength = inputs.Select(a => a.Length).Max();

        //Pad all the numbers to the left with zeroes
        var padded = inputs.Select(a => a.PadLeft(maxLength, '0'));

        //Now sort them
        var sorted = padded.OrderBy(a => a);

        foreach (var s in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases sorting can be done in two steps.

1.Sort based on length of the string. (Remove any leading Zeros).

2.Sort the strings after that.

```
string[] numbers = { "9", "33", "11", "22", "723", "8", "77715926535897932384626433832795" };   
Array.Sort(numbers, (x, y) =>
            {
                int val = x.Length - y.Length;
                if (val == 0)
                {
                    val = x.CompareTo(y);
                }
                return val;
            });
```

Output:

```
"8"
"9"
"11"
"22"
"33"
"723"
"909"
"77715926535897932384626433832795"
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but your proposed solution doesn't really sort as it only comparing length of string and hence trying input `string[] numbers = { "33", "22", "11" };    ` will return the exact sequence

Comment: Sorry, My bad, I forgot to add the second part of logic. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer at other site as below:

```
   string[] unsorted = { "77715926535897932384626433832795", "2398798734", "11" }; 

    Array.Sort(unsorted,(string a,string b) => {
        if(a.Length == b.Length)
            return string.Compare(a,b,StringComparison.Ordinal);
        return a.Length - b.Length;
    });
```

If I understand it correctly, this will compare each and every element using RAW bytes and hence most efficient.